# How do I only show a list of alarms to the user to select from, that does not include ringtones or other sounds

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am currently working on an alarm app, and I want the user to be able to choose what they want for there alarm sound. I display a list to the user that has Alarm, Ringtones, Music, and None. If they tap on Alarm I would like to only show available alarms to the user to choose from. I currently somewhat have Ringtones working where the list is displayed using the RingtonManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER. Also None works as well.

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AlarmList);
    ArrayList<String> alarmChoices = new ArrayList<String>();
    alarmChoices.add("Alarm");
    alarmChoices.add("Ringtone");
    alarmChoices.add("Music");
    alarmChoices.add("None");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.alarmlisttextview, alarmChoices);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    //need to show alarms list
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent setRingtone = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
                    startActivityForResult(setRingtone, 1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //need to show music list
                    break;
                case 3:
                    session.storeAlarm("None");
                    Intent goToStartTimer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartTimer.class);
                    startActivity(goToStartTimer);
                    break;
            }


        }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                Uri alarmTone = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);


                Intent goToStartTimer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartTimer.class);

                session.storeAlarm(alarmTone.toString());
                startActivity(goToStartTimer);
                break;
            }
            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: post your code or screenshots.